# what is the earliest point in a wordpress page load where I can detect the post that is being requested?

Tags: wordpress, action

what is the earliest wordpress action where the post that will eventually be shown can be detected reliably ? (either by using global $post or detecting the wp_query object or other way)

eg. my plugin needs to detect an incoming request from another plugin on a different site, at the moment it checks for a $_POST var as early as possible by using `add_action('plugins_loaded'` and the callback function uses `$post = get_page_by_path($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'','post')` to get the $post object and then uses the post data to get any other information that is used to process the response which gets sent back before any headers or other standard WP processing happens with the intention of lessening the load on the blog receiving the request.

is there a better way?, I know there isn't an earlier way because `'plugins_loaded'` action gets called right after the , well, plugins get loaded but is there a more reliable way than using get_page_by_path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d try the filter `'the_posts'`. You find it in `wp-includes/query.php` function `get_posts()`. It passes the found posts as a array by reference, so you can use it like an action.

Here is a plugin I use to inspect hooks:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Hook Check
Description: Inspects a hook and prints its information to the footer.
Version:     1.0
Required:    3.1
Author:      Thomas Scholz
Author URI:  http://toscho.de
License:     GPL
*/
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) and exit;

$GLOBALS['hook_checks'] = apply_filters(
    'hook_check_filter'
,   array ( 'the_posts' )
);

foreach ( $GLOBALS['hook_checks'] as $hc_hook )
{
    add_action( $hc_hook, array( 'Hook_Check', 'catch_info' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', array( 'Hook_Check', 'print_info' ) );

class Hook_Check
{
    static $info = array ();

    public static function catch_info()
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        self::$info[ current_filter() ] = print_r( $args, TRUE );
        return $args[0];
    }

    public static function print_info()
    {
        if ( empty ( self::$info ) )
        {
            return;
        }

        print '<pre>';
        foreach ( self::$info as $filter => $catched )
        {
            print "<b>$filter</b>\n" . htmlspecialchars( $catched );
        }
        print '</pre>';
    }
}
```

Reduced sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 112
                    [post_content] => The entire content …
                    [post_title] => An awesome title
                    [post_excerpt] => 
                    [post_status] => publish
                )
        )
)
```

This should give you all information you need as early as possible.

Oh, and I hope to see you on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ with such questions. :)

Comment: thanks but doesn't the get_posts() function run _after_ the headers have been sent? I need to send my own headers and content and then exit before anything else has been sent by wordpress.
I see parse_query that runs before send_headers using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to determine the post/page being requested so I guess it will be good enough for me too¬ :-)
thanks for your answer, I'll direct other WP related questions to wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @CommentLuv Yes, it runs later, but you can still replace the original headers because it runs before any output.

Comment: yes, I suppose that's true. I guess having the post object is going to be cleaner than fudging it with the path to post object function